# sql server get min time?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, max, min

Here the question,

I have a table called `attendance` with 4 columns:

```
[Username] varchar(256)
[Date] varchar(256)
[Time] varchar(256)
[Action] varchar(256)
```

What I wish to achieve is to get the first Check In and out time and Last Check In and out time. If there is only one Check In and out row in the table, it return the same.

Sample data like this:

```
Username | Date       | Time     | Action
--------------------------------------------
User1    | 01/12/2012 | 12:54:41 | Check In
User1    | 01/12/2012 | 18:26:36 | Check Out
User1    | 01/12/2012 | 18:44:17 | Check In
User1    | 01/12/2012 | 22:05:31 | Check Out
```

My expected result show below:

```
Output:
Username | Date       | First In | First Out | Last In  | Last Out
User1    | 01/12/2012 | 12:54:41 | 18:26:36  | 18:44:17 | 22:05:31
```

I tried with this SQL statement:

```
SELECT [USERNAME], [DATE]
, min(case when [action] = 'Clock In' then [time] else '' end) as 'First in'
, min(case when [action] = 'Clock Out' then [time] else '' end )as 'First out'
, max(case when [action] = 'Clock In' then [time] else '' end) as 'Last in'
, max(case when [action] = 'Clock Out' then [time] else '' end )as 'Last out'
FROM attendance
WHERE [USERNAME] = 'User1' AND [DATE] = '01/12/2012'
group by [username],[date]
```

It returns unexpected result that my min value always '' or empty but both my max value
'Last in' and 'Last Out' is in correct value.

```
Output:
Username | Date       | First In | First Out | Last In  | Last Out
User1    | 01/12/2012 |          |           | 18:44:17 | 22:05:31
```

Is there any wrong with my SQL?

Can anyone give any suggestion?

Comment: Store date and time as a DateTime?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Nope..both in varchar(256)

Comment: I think Tony's comment was a suggestion for one way to improve your database - you really should use appropriate date types to store values, rather than making everything `varchar(256)`. Unless you think `'the day after my birthday'` (for example) is a suitable value to store in the `Date` column.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ya, i understand what you mean. problem is the system is going life for a quite a long time already. Its difficult to do migration of data.Thanks for your advice anyway.

Comment: Read (and follow!) this: [Bad habits to kick - using the **wrong** datatypes](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: @marc_s noted with thanks, it is a nice Article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT [USERNAME], [DATE]
, min(case when [action] = 'Clock In' then [time]  end) as 'First in'
, min(case when [action] = 'Clock Out' then [time] end )as 'First out'
, max(case when [action] = 'Clock In' then [time] end) as 'Last in'
, max(case when [action] = 'Clock Out' then [time] end )as 'Last out'
FROM attendance
WHERE [USERNAME] = 'User1' AND [DATE] = '01/12/2012'
group by [username],[date]
```

Are you understand where is the problem?

Comment: Not really understand, is the '' a problem if there is no value?

Comment: can you explain more about it ? why cant i used 'else ''"?

Comment: The empty string is less of any string thus min always returns empty string

Comment: Hi @Hamlet Hakobyan, how if the value return null?
Can i wrote like this?
IsNull(min(case when [action] = 'Clock Out' then [time] end),'' )as 'First out'

Comment: Tested, No problem with  IsNull(min(case when [action] = 'Clock Out' then [time] end),'' )as 'First out'

Answer (score 2):

I would do this slightly different using `row_number()`:

```
select username, date,
  max(case when [action] = 'Check In' and rn=1 then time end) FirstIn,
  max(case when [action] = 'Check Out' and rn=1 then time end) FirstOut,
  max(case when [action] = 'Check In' and rn=2 then time end) LastIn,
  max(case when [action] = 'Check Out' and rn=2 then time end) LastOut
from
(
  select username, cast(date as date) date, 
    cast(time as time) time, 
    action,
    row_number() 
      over(partition by username, cast(date as date), action
           order by cast(time as time)) rn
  from attendance
) src
group by username, date;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4bf82/19)

The result is:

```
| USERNAME |       DATE |          FIRSTIN |         FIRSTOUT |           LASTIN |          LASTOUT |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    User1 | 2012-01-12 | 12:54:41.0000000 | 18:26:36.0000000 | 18:44:17.0000000 | 22:05:31.0000000 |
```

I would strongly suggest that you store your `date` and `time` as a `datetime` datatype.

*Note:* I changed the value from `Clock In`/`Clock Out` to `Check In`/`Check Out` to match the sample data you provided.

Comment: Thanks @bluefeet, its a good solution too.
but i think this is somehow to difficult to such newbie for me..
btw, Sql fiddle is nice...dint know about it before u told me.

Comment: @LiangCk [`row_number() over(partition by)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) generates a sequential number based on your data.  Basically, the query is saying to only sequence the number if the `username`, `date` and `action` are the same. If so, then increase the number, if not, then start with a new sequence. `row_number()` is very helpful for these types of queries.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @first_in VARCHAR, @first_out VARCHAR, @last_in VARCHAR, @last_out VARCHAR
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1
     @first_in = time
FROM attendance
WHERE [USERNAME] = 'User1' AND [DATE] = '01/12/2012' AND [ACTION] = 'first in'
ORDER BY time ASC


SELECT TOP 1
     @first_in = time
FROM attendance
WHERE [USERNAME] = 'User1' AND [DATE] = '01/12/2012' AND [ACTION] = 'first out'
ORDER BY time ASC

SELECT TOP 1
     @last_in = time
FROM attendance
WHERE [USERNAME] = 'User1' AND [DATE] = '01/12/2012' AND [ACTION] = 'first in'
ORDER BY time DESC

SELECT TOP 1
     @last_out = time
FROM attendance
WHERE [USERNAME] = 'User1' AND [DATE] = '01/12/2012' AND [ACTION] = 'first out'
ORDER BY time DESC

SELECT 'User1','01/12/2012', @first_in, @first_out, @last_in, @last_out
END
```

Comment: i used this before i change the Sql, what my colleague concern is about the performance issues.Execute 4 select statement is not better then 1 select statement, anyway. thanks for your advice.